# how to call a function when click on button in pyfltk

Tags: python, user-interface, fltk

I want to call a function when `Fl_Button` pressed. how ?

this is example code:

```py
from fltk import *
win = Fl_Window(150, 200, 'Test')

def test():
     print("Function Called") # I want this function to be called when press the btn

btn = Fl_Button(40, 120, 60, 30, 'Resault'); res_btn.box(FL_PLASTIC_UP_BOX)

win.show(sys.argv); Fl_run()
```

Thanks!

Comment: please help if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the button.callback method.

See https://pyfltk.sourceforge.io/docs/CH3_Common.html in the Callbacks section

Comment: Nice, but if I want shortcut?

Comment: Shortcuts are in the next section after callbacks.  You didn't ask about shortcuts in the original question.  I'm guessing you haven't read it yet - it is only 5 lines excluding example otherwise you would have seen the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the examples that ship with pyFltk? There is a plethora of examples, many of which address the very specific issue you are currently looking at.

For instance, this is the example called button.py, which highlights a few more things you can do with callbacks:

```
from fltk import *
import sys

window = None

class MyButton(Fl_Button):
    data = "My Secret Data"
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, l):
        Fl_Button.__init__(self, x, y, w, h, l)
    
def beepcb(ptr, widget):
    print("beepcb: ")
    print("  Widget member: ",ptr.data)

def exitcb(ptr, widget):
    sys.exit(0)

window = Fl_Window(100,100,320, 65,"Button")
b1 = MyButton(20,20,80,25, "Beep")

b1.callback(beepcb, window)
b2 = Fl_Button(120,20, 80, 25, "&no op")
b3 = Fl_Button(220,20, 80, 25, "Exit");
b3.callback(exitcb,window)
window.end()

window.show()
Fl.run()
```

Good luck

Andreas